# $Y_n$ integrable and equally distributed $\implies\frac{Y_n}{n}\overset{\mathrm{a.s.}}{\rightarrow}0$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X, Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ be equally distributed, $E(|X|)<\infty$. $\frac{Y_n}{n}\overset{\mathrm{a.s.}}{\rightarrow}0$?

---

**Comments**

- $\frac{Y_n}{n}\overset{P}{\rightarrow}0$. Indeed since $Y_n\sim X$,
  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left(\left|\frac{Y_n}{n}\right|<\varepsilon\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left(\left|X\right|<n\varepsilon\right)=1$$
- With a bit more effort i've been able to devise a counterexample with $P\left(|X|<\infty\right)=1$ but $E(|X|)=\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Show that for all $\varepsilon>0$, $\sum_nP(|Y_n|>n\varepsilon)<\infty$, using integrability of $X$.
2. Conclude by Borel-Cantelli's lemma.

Comment: Brilliantly simple! Thanks.